# Disprove Euler's sum-of-powers conjecture

Tags: beginner, rust

Problem statement: In 1769 Leonhard Euler formulated a generalized version of Fermat's Last Theorem, conjecturing that at least \$n\$ \$\text{n}_{\text{th}}\$ powers are needed to obtain a sum that is itself an \$\text{n}_{\text{th}}\$ power, for \$n > 2\$. Write a program to disprove Euler's conjecture (which stood until 1967). That is, find \$a\$, \$b\$, \$c\$, \$d\$, and \$e\$ such that \$a^5 + b^5 + c^5 + d^5 = e^5\$.

This is one of my self-imposed challenges in Rust to become better at it. The problem was taken from [Sedgewick Exercise 1.3.46](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/home/).

Here is my code:

```
use clap::Parser;
use std::ops::RangeFrom;
use std::process::exit;

type Euler = Vec<(usize, usize, usize, usize, usize)>;
const VALID_SEARCH_UPPER_BOUNDS: RangeFrom<usize> = 1..;

#[derive(Debug, Parser)]
struct Arguments {
    #[arg(index = 1)]
    search_upper_bound: usize,
}

fn main() {
    let arguments = Arguments::parse();
    let search_upper_bound = arguments.search_upper_bound;

    let Ok(numbers) = disprove_euler_conjecture(search_upper_bound) else {
        eprintln!("Search upper bound must be at least {}.", VALID_SEARCH_UPPER_BOUNDS.start);
        exit(1);
    };

    if numbers.is_empty() {
        eprintln!("Search upper bound is too small.")
    } else {
        for tuple in numbers {
            let a = tuple.0;
            let b = tuple.1;
            let c = tuple.2;
            let d = tuple.3;
            let e = tuple.4;

            println!("{a}⁵ + {b}⁵ + {c}⁵ + {d}⁵ = {e}⁵");
        }
    }
}

fn disprove_euler_conjecture(search_upper_bound: usize) -> Result<Euler, String> {
    if !VALID_SEARCH_UPPER_BOUNDS.contains(&search_upper_bound) {
        return Err(format!(
            "Search upper bound must be at least {}.",
            VALID_SEARCH_UPPER_BOUNDS.start,
        ));
    }

    let mut numbers: Vec<(usize, usize, usize, usize, usize)> = Vec::new();

    for e in 1..search_upper_bound {
        let e5 = e.pow(5);

        for a in 1..search_upper_bound {
            let a5 = a.pow(5);

            if a5 > e5 {
                break;
            }

            for b in a..search_upper_bound {
                let b5 = b.pow(5);

                if a5 + b5 > e5 {
                    break;
                }

                for c in b..search_upper_bound {
                    let c5 = c.pow(5);

                    if a5 + b5 + c5 > e5 {
                        break;
                    }

                    for d in c..search_upper_bound {
                        let d5 = d.pow(5);

                        if a5 + b5 + c5 + d5 > e5 {
                            break;
                        }

                        if a5 + b5 + c5 + d5 == e5 {
                            numbers.push((a, b, c, d, e));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Ok(numbers)
}
```

Is there any way that I can improve my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another good question, and much of the advice I gave [on your previous one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286003/find-ramanujan-hardy-numbers-smaller-than-n) applies.  I’ll try to repeat myself as little as possible.

#### The Loops Could be Improved

Currently you have a deeply-nested loop whose layers all have code like

```rust
        for a in 1..search_upper_bound {
            let a5 = a.pow(5);

            if a5 > e5 {
                break;
            }
```

This performs two checks and conditional branches per iteration, which are slow.  A vectorizing or parallelizing compiler probably won’t know what to do with it, either.

It also means that the declared range of the loop is actively misleading, and the actual termination check is a `break` inside the loop, where a maintainer might not think to look.  It would be better to compute the bounds of the search before starting it, and set the range of the loop to that.  Next best would be to set the range to `1,,`, `a..`, `b..` or something like that, or even use a `loop` with no condition, to make it obvious that something within the loop must `break`.

#### Eliminate at Least One Level of the Loop

What jumps out at me is, there’s a valid Diophantine solution for *a⁵* + *b⁵* + *c⁵* + *d⁵* = *e⁵*, if and only if, for some *a*, there is a solution to *b⁵* + *c⁵* + *d⁵* = *e⁵* - *a⁵*, there’s a solution to that if and only if, given *a* and *b*, there’s a solution for *c⁵* + *d⁵* = *e⁵* - *a⁵* - *b⁵*. and at that point, given *c*, you can directly solve for *d*.

#### Consider a Tail-Recursive Implementation

I wouldn’t recommend this as easily in Rust as I would in a language that guaranteed tail-call optimization.  However, the four steps of the algorithm I outlined above could be expressed as four helper functions, three of which might be one-liners using `flat_map`.  That would be easier to read and maintain.

#### Use Pattern Destructuring

You currently have:

```rust
        for tuple in numbers {
            let a = tuple.0;
            let b = tuple.1;
            let c = tuple.2;
            let d = tuple.3;
            let e = tuple.4;
```

This could be:

```
 for (a,b,c,d,e) in numbers {
```

#### Avoid Passing Unrecoverable Logic Errors up the Stack

Currently, you’re returning a `Result` that can only fail if the search is called with an incorrect set of bounds.  But that is a logic error, not something you want to have to check every call for.  It *could* happen at runtime, if you’re reading the bounds from user input, but in this case, I think I would have `disprove_euler_conjecture` just panic if called with invalid inputs.  In fact, is there a compelling reason the bound needs to be user-specified at all?  The function just searches for a counterexample, and could treat any suggestion you give it about a bound as an advisory hint.

The caller is currently checking for this error anyway (in fact, it completely ignores the `Err` value and assumes there’s only one kind of error, an indication that this should actually be an `Option` instead of a `Result`), and aborting, so there’s no benefit to returning `Err` in this program.  In fact, that’s worse for debugging, because you’ve partially unwound the stack and lost both the value that caused the bug and the line of code where it was detected!  If you had instead called `panic!` within `disprove_euler_conjecture`, you can often set `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` and get a lot of the information reproducing the bug in a debugger would have given you.  Although you never want the end user to see a panic, it’s a great way to catch logic errors that should be eliminated.

In the rare situation that you are reading in the bound dynamically at runtime, the caller can check the value.

#### Consider a More Intuitive Return Type

You currently return a `Result` where failure to find a counterexample is represented by `Ok (vec![])`.  It’s counterintuitive to have to unwrap the return object and then also check that the unwrapped value is valid.  You also are searching the entire space first and then finding all counterexamples, rather than stopping when you find the first.

The return type should probably be `Option<(usize, usize, usize, usize, usize)>`.

#### Prefer Iterator Expressions to Appending

There would be some new syntax to learn if you turn the loop into an expression  with type `impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize, usize, usize, usize)>`, but that have several advantages.

One is that iterators can evaluate lazily and short-circuit when they find a counterexample.  That probably removes the motivation for you to implement this as a function that searches a block and can restart at a certain range.  You’re probably only doing it that way because you have to search the whole range before returning any results.

Another is that you can easily take the same code to generate the solutions and have it return a short-circuiting `Option` by adding `.nth(1)` at the end, or fill any collection with them by adding `.collect()`.  Or you could call `Iterator::for_each` on it, or use it as the range expression of a `for` loop, to print each value found immediately and keep searching.  It’s extremely flexible!

Another is that you can often get an expression that it’s easier to prove correct than a loop whose termination conditions are buried in a `break` statement nested five levels deep.

Mainly, though, mutable variables can have several categories of bugs that immutable state cannot, so you should be getting some significant benefit from mutable data to make up for that.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good scenario for a struct again, which represents our desired states.
On it, we can implement its generation function and implement the `Display` trait to be directly able to print it.
As other reviewers have already pointed out, the loops can be optimized as well. Again I'll use chained maps and filters here.

`Cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "euler"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
clap = { version = "4.3.12", features = ["derive"] }
```

`src/lib.rs`

```rust
use std::fmt::{Display, Formatter};

pub struct EulerQuintet {
    a: u64,
    b: u64,
    c: u64,
    d: u64,
    e: u64,
}

impl EulerQuintet {
    pub fn generate(limit: u64) -> impl Iterator<Item = Self> {
        (1..=limit).flat_map(move |a| {
            (a..=limit).flat_map(move |b| {
                (b..=limit).flat_map(move |c| {
                    (c..=limit).flat_map(move |d| {
                        (d..=limit).filter_map(move |e| {
                            if a.pow(5) + b.pow(5) + c.pow(5) + d.pow(5) == e.pow(5) {
                                Some(Self { a, b, c, d, e })
                            } else {
                                None
                            }
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    }
}

impl Display for EulerQuintet {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(
            f,
            "{}⁵ + {}⁵ + {}⁵ + {}⁵ = {}⁵",
            self.a, self.b, self.c, self.d, self.e
        )
    }
}
```

`src/main.rs`

```rust
use clap::Parser;
use euler::EulerQuintet;
use std::process::exit;

#[derive(Debug, Parser)]
struct Arguments {
    #[arg(index = 1)]
    search_upper_bound: u64,
}

fn main() {
    let arguments = Arguments::parse();
    let euler_quintets: Vec<_> = EulerQuintet::generate(arguments.search_upper_bound).collect();

    if euler_quintets.is_empty() {
        eprintln!("Upper bound too low.");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        for quintet in euler_quintets {
            println!("{quintet}");
        }
    }
}
```

Also for numerical work I'd not use the rather magic `usize`, but one of the explicit integer sizes (`u64` here). `usize` is meant to be used when handling memory and addresses, but it's weird to read in algorithms that do higher level math stuff.